# Cómo ejecuto un PROCEDIMIENTO dentro de una FUNCION en SQL/PL ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

El procedimiento es este:

```
create or replace procedure ro(m number,n number)
```

Que llena una tabla

Externamente uso estas dos lineas para ejecutar:

```
truncate TABLE tob;             
exec ro(1,floor(sqrt(n)));
```

Quiero saber si puedo ejecutar las dos lineas anteriores de ejecución dentro de esta función cada vez que yo la use.

```
create or replace function primo(n NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible desde una función en PL/SQL ejecutar SQL dinámico y llamar  procedimientos, incluso puede tener parámetros de salida.

Sin embargo se **supone** que una función solo consulta información, o realiza cálculos pero no realiza modificación de los datos almacenados y por lo tanto **no es una buena práctica** y se desaconseja que una función modifique datos de una tabla (insertar, actualizar, borrar), o modifique la estructura de una tabla o llame procedimientos que hagan modificaciones a los datos de una tabla (insertar, actualizar, borrar).

Ejemplo realizado en Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0:

```
create table tob
(codigo     number,
 resultado  number
)
/


create or replace procedure ro(m number,n number)
is
Begin
  insert into tob values (m,n);
End;
/


Create or replace function fnuRaiz(m number,
                                   n number
                                  )
return number
is
  nuValor  number;
Begin
  execute immediate 'truncate TABLE tob';
  ro(m,floor(sqrt(n)));
  --
  select resultado
  into nuValor
  from tob;
  return(nuValor);
End fnuRaiz;
/


Declare
 nuRaiz number;
begin
  nuRaiz:=fnuRaiz(1,101);
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('nuRaiz='||nuRaiz);
End;
/
```

Y la salida es:

```
nuRaiz=10                      
Total execution time 63 ms
```